# How to get output from helper for path argument in layout?

Tags: magento2

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="custommodule/general/enable_footer_link" name="custommodule-link">
<arguments>
    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Module</argument>
    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" helper="NS\CustomModule\Helper\Data::getFrontName()"/>
</arguments>
</block>
```

I'm trying this in default.xml. how can i get a string from helper action for the `path` argument?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="custommodule/general/enable_footer_link" name="custommodule-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Module</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="NS\CustomModule\Helper\Data::getFrontName"/>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

You can also pass parameters for the method like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="custommodule/general/enable_footer_link" name="custommodule-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Module</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="NS\CustomModule\Helper\Data::getFrontName">
            <param name="name">value</param>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) For ex: you have function getTitle() in Data.php at Namespace/Modulename/Helper**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
       return "Testing";
    }

}
```

**2) In layout.xml change xsi:type="string" to xsi:type="helper" and define helper class::methodName**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="custommodule/general/enable_footer_link" name="custommodule-link">
<arguments>
    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Module</argument>
    <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data::getTitle"/>
</arguments>
</block>
```