# Magento 2 : Get value from system configuration in layout XML

Tags: magento2, layout, system-configuration

how do I get my module link identifier in the footer from the **core config values** I set in the **admin system configuration**

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="storelocator-policy-link">
            <arguments >
                <argument ifconfig="googlemapsstorelocator/general/enable" name="label" xsi:type="string">Google Maps Store Locator</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">I need this value form the configuration settings</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write a "helper" (a method in any class of your module) and use `xsi:type="helper` as described here: [How to get output from helper for path argument in layout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97937/how-to-get-output-from-helper-for-path-argument-in-layout)

You should do the same for the first argument, because the `argument` element cannot have an  `ifconfig` attribute (or move `ifconfig` to the `block` to not add it at all if the "enable" configuration is not set).