# How to get output from helper for attribute value in layout?

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to pass a helper as parameter for attribute class in layout XML, like I did sometimes in M1.

The layout XML currently looks like:

```xml
<body>
   <attribute name="class">
            <argument name="value" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Module\Helper\Data::getCssNameRegion"/>
   </attribute>
</body>
```

The helper will return a string like "region-us", "region-uk", and so on.

I'm just trying to make `<attribute name="class" value="FROMHELPER"/>` bring the value from there.

How to do that in M2?

In [this other question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97937/how-to-get-output-from-helper-for-path-argument-in-layout) the user asks about other kind of usage, but I was unable to replicate for attribute node.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to workaround the situation was use core/text block and add a JS to add the class. Poor, but didn't find a better solution yet.

```
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="bodyClassScript">
            <action method="setText">
                <argument name="value" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Module\Helper\Data::getJsRegion"/>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```