# Populate data from db on custom select Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hello I have already created a custom module that add a select drop-down field to the checkout step, at this moment i have the values populated hard coded, by i need to get them from db, how can i do that? This is my checkout_index_index.xml extended xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
<arguments>
<argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
<item name="components" xsi:type="array">
<item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/js/view/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
<item name="checkout_buyer_email" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
<item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_email</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Buyer Name</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
</item>
<item name="checkout_buyer_name" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
<item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
</item>
<!-- Added for drop down values hard coded-->
<item name="options" xsi:type="array">
<item name="0" xsi:type="array">
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please Select</item>
<item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
</item>
<item name="1" xsi:type="array">
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">My Value</item>
<item name="value" xsi:type="string">My Value</item>
</item>
<item name="2" xsi:type="array">
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">My Value</item>
<item name="value" xsi:type="string">My Value</item>
</item>
<item name="3" xsi:type="array">
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">My Value</item>
<item name="value" xsi:type="string">My Value</item>
</item>

</item>
<!-- Added for drop down values hard coded -->
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_name</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please Select</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
</item>

</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</item>
</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a helper and use it in the xsi:type of your items. In the helper you will have to create functions to retrieve those admin values using scopeConfig.

[How to get output from helper for path argument in layout?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97937/how-to-get-output-from-helper-for-path-argument-in-layout)

How to create custom admin values :

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html